# how to curry a method?

Tags: ruby

consider this code

```
def f x, y
  x + y
end

g = lambda(&method(:f)).curry.(1)

g.(2) # => 3
```

the expression for `g` is too hard to read. Can it be simplified?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the shortest (and most readable!) you can get is

```
  g = method(:f).to_proc.curry[1]
  g[2] # => 3
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Ruby 2.2.0 or later, you can use [Method#curry](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-trunk/Method.html#method-i-curry):

```
def f(x, y)
  x + y
end
g = method(:f).curry[1]
p g[2] # => 3
```